# How to get PDF file in REST API in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, rest, filestream, restful-url

I'm getting pdf file from REST API in folowing code line

---

```
 response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;// HttpWebResponse response
```

and I use stream reader to get the response

```
            if (response != null)
            {
                rchResponseHeader.Text = response.Headers.ToString();
                //string resBody = null;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    resBody = reader.ReadToEnd();//string resBody
                }
             }
```

And I save the file as follows using filedialogBox and pdf extension

```
      if (saveDialogBox.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string name = saveDialogBox.FileName;
                File.WriteAllText(name, resBody);
            }
```

file save successfully but I cannot open the file: and I believe the way I used to read the file and write is not appropriate. is there way to make this sucess
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are reading and writing a binary file as text. That can't work.

Use something like this instead:

```
if (response != null)
{
    rchResponseHeader.Text = response.Headers.ToString();

    if (saveDialogBox.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using(var fileStream = File.Open(name, ...))
        {
            response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```